# Issus in Xcode 4 editor

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5

I made edit in the scoop in Xcode (4.5) but now every thing in the editor is like the below image. how to stop this
[image]

and this another screenshot

[image]
it's becomes very hard to use the editor. I tried to reset the Xcode setting but nothing happen

Comment: What is the problem with the screenshot, and what did you edit in the scoop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the menu, select "Editor -> Code Folding -> Focus Follows Selection".